# is there any possible way to assign static ip address to android devices in wifi direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct

consider 4 android devices connected using WiFi direct and one device is the group owner.And the go has to assign the static IP address.

I have read some documentations but i didn't get any expected answer. do u have any suggestions?

Note that It would be good if no routing is required.